# Problem in displaying correct header notes

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am currently facing in one of the page where the last line ended by only chapter, in that page its unable to show the chapter number in the header, , every chpater number that we see is the verse number for that chapter, so i was unable to acomplished that format, however if the last line is not ended by chapter then it is working fine. So how do i achived this to display correct chapter number and verse, her is my MWE which i tried so far. Any suggestion?

```
 \documentclass[twoside,letterpaper,11pt,openany]{book}

  \usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{titletoc} %%% Table of contents 
  \usepackage{ebgaramond}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{paracol}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark} %% display chapter in header
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} %% To display numbering on every page alternately left and right

  \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
  \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
  \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
  \usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}

  %%%% End Add
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
  \newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}
  \renewcommand\paragraph{%
    \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                  {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%
                  {-.5em}%
                  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%
  \newlength{\biblechapskip}
    \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .33em minus .2em}
  \newcounter{biblechapter}
  \newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]
  \renewcommand\chaptername{Book}
  \let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
  \let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph
  \newcommand{\book}[1]{%
    \gdef\currbook{#1}
    \ltx@chapter{#1}}
  \newcount\biblechap@svdopt
  \newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]
    {\biblechap@svdopt=#1
    \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else
      \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi
    \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}
    \refstepcounter{biblechapter}
    \lettrine{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-6pt\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}
    {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}
  \renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%
    \refstepcounter{bibleverse}
    \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}
    \ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else
      \ltx@paragraph*{#1}\fi}%
  \makeatother


  \newcounter{jChapter}
  \newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{
  \noindent\scalebox{2.5}{\color{red}\textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}}
  \setcounter{jChapter}{#1}
  }  
  \newcommand{\jverse}[1]{\noindent\textcolor{cyan}{\scalebox{1.0}{\textbf{#1\hspace{1.0mm}}}}\markboth{\scshape \currbook\ \thejChapter : #1}{} }
  \newcommand{\story}[1]{\vfill\noindent\parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\centering\it\textbf{#1}}}% \centering contained within \parbox

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \newcommand{\storygap}{\vfill\ensurevspace{3\baselineskip}\switchcolumn*}% paracol specific code
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \title{Translation}
  \date{}
  \author{}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \newcommand{\BookLine}{ \centering\noindent\rule{19cm}{1pt}}
  \newcommand{\BookNote}[1]{{\begin{center} \textbf{KEPACHINI} \justify

  #1
  \end{center}
  \BookLine
  \vspace{2mm}
  }}

  \newcommand{\ParallelLText}[2]{\switchcolumn[0] #1\par \switchcolumn[1] #2\par \switchcolumn*}

  \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages

  \usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}

  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} %set depth of printed table of contets.

  \makeatletter


  \patchcmd{\l@section}
    {\hfil}
    {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep     mu$}\hfill}
    {}{}

  \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
      \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
          \@mkboth{%
             \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
      \printlist{toc}{}{}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
      \end{multicols}%
      }

  \makeatother %print dots in sections in toc.


 %%% Command to make uppercase for every first letter
 \usepackage{mfirstuc}
 \MFUnocap{are}
 \MFUnocap{or}
 \MFUnocap{etc}

 \newcommand{\athepi}{\textbf{\capitalisewords{Athepi Alamthe Hei Hei}}\\}
 \usepackage{enumitem}



 \begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
 %\frontmatter
 %\maketitle
 %\tableofcontents
 %
 %\mainmatter



 \frontmatter
 \maketitle
 {\setlength{\columnsep}{130pt}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\Huge Kechejok Barim\hfill~\\[2.5ex] }
 \startlist{toc}
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
 \tableofcontents
 }
 \mainmatter

 {\pagenumbering{gobble}
 \part*{\scshape Kechejok Barim}
 }
 \pagenumbering{arabic}  
   \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 \book{Kecheng}
 %\BookNote{ \input{Book/Kepachini/GenesisI.tex} }
 \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy
 \ParallelLText{\jChapter{23}HEMPHU  nang Arnam nangtum angno pen halatum aphan nangphlung pipo. Lapen nangtum chedanbom ahut HEMPHU  halatum aphan nangphlung pi-etpo, nangtum Arnam HEMPHU  kechedan asonthot.  }{\jChapter{23}The LORD your God will push them back before you, and drive them out of your sight; and you shall possess their land, as the LORD your God promised you. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{6}Lasi kekroi thekjile cherenon lapen Moses Aron aloh along ketok ason an klemnon. La esonbakta klem pa-oiri,  }{\jverse{6}Therefore be very steadfast to observe and do all that is written in the book of the law of Moses, turning aside from it neither to the right nor to the left, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{7}lapen nangtum angbong kedo laso ahin arat atum pen nangtum chelang nangnelo mate halatum a-arnam-heihei amen parno dun nangnelo mate halahei amen pen semetang nangne mate halahei arnam aphan archo nangne mate halatum aphan ardom nangne.  }{\jverse{7}so that you may not be mixed with these nations left here among you, or make mention of the names of their gods, or swear by them, or serve them, or bow yourselves down to them, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{8}Alar HEMPHU  aphanle kroithipnon, non nangtum kedo ason.  }{\jverse{8}but hold fast to the LORD your God, as you have done to this day. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{9}Nangtum kechedan ahut kethedung lapen kangtangrak akhei atum ta HEMPHU  phlungtang-lo lapen nangtum angno karjap unji abang baduta avelo.  }{\jverse{9}For the LORD has driven out before you great and strong nations; and as for you, no one has been able to withstand you to this day. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{10}Nangtum inutbak anta bangsuri aphan phlung unji pima Alangli kechechak asonsi HEMPHU  nangtum aphan nang chedanpipo.  }{\jverse{10}One of you puts to flight a thousand, since it is the LORD your God who fights for you, as he promised you. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{11}Nang Arnam HEMPHU  aphan kechinghonjile cheretu.  }{\jverse{11}Be very careful, therefore, to love the LORD your God. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{12}Nangtum jongsi kroikrera lapen nangtum angbong kedo ahin arat akhei kaprek along chelangdun pen piso chepangriseroi lote  }{\jverse{12}For if you turn back, and join the survivors of these nations left here among you, and intermarry with them, so that you marry their women and they yours, }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{13}angtum chininon nangtum kechedan ahut seta HEMPHU  halahei akheiso aphan phlungphlelo. Kalite nangtum aphan halatum isi kepherememe apham ason mate hilik lapen isi nangnung angthum ason mate nangmek angsu ason plangpo. Lapen nang Arnam HEMPHU  nang kepi alongle keme along nangtum vir-et-etik ke la plangverpo.” }{\jverse{13}know assuredly that the LORD your God will not continue to drive out these nations before you; but they shall be a snare and a trap for you, a scourge on your sides, and thorns in your eyes, until you perish from this good land that the LORD your God has given you. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{14}Non ne kethi apor nangletang-lo. Alangli kechechak atengsi nang Arnam HEMPHU  kedo-an akeme amar nangpitang-lo pu nangtum abangphutinta chinipame. Alangli kechechak athetin atengsi Alangli klemlo; ethenat ta keklemkle avelo.  }{\jverse{14}“And now I am about to go the way of all the earth, and you know in your hearts and souls, all of you, that not one thing has failed of all the good things that the LORD your God promised concerning you; all have come to pass for you, not one of them has failed. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{15}Nangtum aphan Alangli kechechak asonthotsi athetinta Alangli klempo.  }{\jverse{15}But just as all the good things that the LORD your God promised concerning you have been fulfilled for you, so the LORD will bring upon you all the bad things, until he has destroyed you from this good land that the LORD your God has given you. }
 \ParallelLText{\jverse{16}Jongsi nang Arnam HEMPHU  nangpaklemtoi ahukum kechejok ateng klemkle lapen kaprek arnam atum aphan ingduk-rong, archorong pulote Alangli aningkethi pen nangtum aphan aduk pipo lapen Alangli nangtum aphan nangkepi alongle keme along nangtum virdetdetik an adukpipo. }{\jverse{16}If you transgress the covenant of the LORD your God, which he enjoined on you, and go and serve other gods and bow down to them, then the anger of the LORD will be kindled against you, and you shall perish quickly from the good land that he has given to you.” }
 \storygap
 \ParallelLText{\story{Shekem Along Joshua Rat Aphan Kethan}}{\story{The Tribes Renew the Covenant}}
 \ParallelLText{\jChapter{24}Shekem along Joshua kedo-an Israel akhei aphan pangrumlo. La akesar atum aphan, jalin atum aphan, kangsai atum aphan lapen Israel achakri atum aphan hangpet-lo lapen halatum HEMPHU  angno vangpet-lo.  }{\jChapter{24}Then Joshua gathered all the tribes of Israel to Shechem, and summoned the elders, the heads, the judges, and the officers of Israel; and they presented themselves before God. }
 \end{paracol}
 \end{document}
```

here is the output of the above MWE, header is showing as `KECHENG 23:16` but correct header should be `KECHENG 24:1`

[image]